# Can we not have abc.c and ABC.c in a same folder? Can someone explain me the reasons

Tags: windows, case-sensitive

I am trying to create 2 c files with a similar name but the only difference is the case. one is in lower case and the other in upper but I keep getting an error on windows

[image]

Comment: Windows uses case-insensitive file and pathnames, so no. This only works on linux/unix.

Comment: The filesystem used by Windows is case insensitive.

Comment: @RamRohitGannavarapu Please insert image in place and not refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows filesystems are case insensitive, that means that `A.txt` and `a.txt` denote the samefile. But the stored filenames are stored as-is, which means that if you created the file as `A.txt` it is shown as-is, but the way you name it doesn't matter.

You can change this behavior on some Windows, but I discourage you doing so.

Comment: Windows XP introduced a default-enabled value named "obcaseinsenstive" in the session-manager "kernel" key. This forces device/file access to be case insensitive even when using call flags such as `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE`. A program shouldn't modify this. Windows 10 supports case-sensitive file access, but as an NTFS directory property rather than using a call flag. Set this via `NtSetInformationFile` : `FileCaseSensitiveInformation`. There's no WINAPI equivalent call, but on the command line there's `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <dirname> enable`.